# accessing file from jmeter beanshell sample using filepath

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to access one file from beanshell sampler. However it shows me error as below :

Encounter "(C:"at line 9, column 2)

file path name is C:/Test/test.txt.
It seems i can't use C:/ drive in beanshell sampler? please let me know how can I resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a syntax error in your Beanshell script, try using the below reference code which is reading the file and prints its contents into *jmeter.log*

```
String test = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:/Test/test.txt"));
log.info("test.txt file content is: " + test);
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Beanshell Read From File]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article to learn more about Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

---

NB: it may be faster and easier to use [__FileToString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function like:

```
${__FileToString(c:\test\test.txt,,)}
```

[image: JMeter FileToString Function]